# Why is that $\mathbb{E}[X|A]\mathbb{P}(A)=\int x \mathbb{I}_{A} dP$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I'd like to prove that:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X|A]\mathbb{P}(A)=\int x \mathbb{I}_{A} dP
$$

This came to me because the "Law of total expectation" would be way easier to prove if I could argue that:

$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int x \mathbb{I}_{(A_i)} dP=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{E}[X|A_i]\mathbb{P}(A_i)
$$

with $A_i$ a partition of $\Omega$.

Comment: maybe you mean $\int X \mathbf{1}_{A}dP$?

Comment: The only partition you need is $\{A, A^\complement\}$, just the two parts rather than an infinite count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $A$ is a set, $Z=\mathbb{E}[X|A]$ is a constant and thus:

$$ZP(A)=Z\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_A]=\mathbb{E}[Z\mathbb{I}_A]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{I}_A|A]]=\mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{I}_A]$$

where we used that $\mathbb{I}_A \in \sigma(A)$ (therefore $ \mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{I}_A|A]=\mathbb{I}_A\mathbb{E}[X|A]$) and the last equality is the tower law.